# Executing java via exec or shell_exec gives error

Tags: java, php, linux, exec, java-7

I have `jdk1.7.0_07` installed on server(linux). The file permission to `~/bin` files are executable(755). However when I tried to execute,

```
$output = exec("/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/java -version 2>&1");
echo $output;
```

It gives permission denied error, I have tried this,

```
$output = exec("java -version 2>&1");
echo $output;
```

Which gives command not found error. While checking my environment variables. I have succesfully added `JAVA_HOME = /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07` and for `PATH = /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin`

#### But,

When I run above mentioned PHP script it keeps giving me those permission denied or command not found error. Any personal experience or clue?

Comment: @Tivie, Nah still this isn't working :(

Comment: I see that you accepted my answer. Does that mean that you solved the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running these commands from the command-line, you probably execute them with your own user permissions. However, when you execute these same commands via a PHP script in a web app, they will be executed with the Apach user (typically www-data) permissions. These means that you cannot rely on the command-line output to debug permission errors unless you can log in as the exact same user that runs your PHP script.

Answer (score 3):

If your OS is CentOS it could come from SELinux.

```
root@ls:~# /usr/sbin/getenforce 
Enforcing
root@ls:~# /usr/sbin/setenforce Permissive
root@ls:~# /usr/sbin/getenforce 
Permissive
```

More detail in https://superuser.com/questions/455935/php-script-cant-run-bash-script-sh-permission-denied

It fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks-you, Thanks-you, Thanks-you, Thanks-you! Been struggling with this all night. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have 2 distinct problems:

If it gives you permission denied error when you give the full path to Java executable, then your permissions are probably incorrect. The most common cause is, somewhere along the path, Apache User (usually www-data) does not have read access. For instance, if www-data does not have read permission for jdk1.7.0_07 directory it can't see (or open) it's child directory called bin.

Regarding the path, it will not work unless permissions are correctly set. However, where did you set your environment PATH? Was it in the user profile?